# Python(консольное меню)

Tags: python

Помогите реализовать консольное меню на основе этого кода

```
def input_data():
    members = []
    a = int(input('Количество участников: '))
    return members, a

def fill_list(members,a):
    for i in range(a):
        name = input('Введите имя: ')
        age = int(input('Введите возраст: '))
        members.append(name + ':'+str(age))
    print('первый список:', members)
    return members



def type_list(members):
    for i in members.copy():
        name,age = i.split(':')
        if int(age) >= 18:
            members.remove(i)
    print('второй список:', members)
    return members


def main():
    members, a=input_data()
    members=fill_list(members,a)
    members=type_list(members)


main()
```

Comment: а логику самим придумать?

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам пример реализации, дополните нужными действиями

```
def menu():
    while True:
        print('1-Перводе действие / 2-Второе действие и тд')
        type = int(input('Ответ: '))
        if type == 1:
            main()
        elif type == 2:
            main()
        elif type == 0:
            exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

На первый взгляд всё работает, если подправить main() вот так:

```
def main():
    input_data()
    members=fill_list(members,a)
    members=type_list(members)
```

т.к. сам массив members и переменная a у вас объявляются в функции input_data(), то не нужно их декларировать и тем более присваивать возврат input_data() в самой функции, а только обновлять, как у вас и сделано далее

А что вы хотите видеть в консольном меню? Не очень понятен вопрос.